# Should I mention planned publications in an application?

Tags: phd, application, application-cover-letter

I am applying for a Ph.D. position but am still finishing my master's thesis. My supervisor and I plan to publish my results. However, it probably will still take some months to be a publishable paper. Probably, I have found a Ph.D. position until then but I might still need to invest some time in my master's paper.
I wonder if it would be beneficial for me to state that I plan to publish my work in the application or if it might rather be harmful because I would create the impression that I cannot 110% focus on the Ph.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, "work in progress" is a valid thing to put into a CV and has positive value in an application. Normally the implication isn't that you won't perform the duties of the position you are applying for unless you otherwise indicate that it might.

And, if the doctoral work is, in any way, an extension of the masters level work then it is even more positive.

Moreover, in most places, the two are unlikely to conflict, though if they do, you will need to make choices, but that is a question for the future and for discussion(s) with your present advisor and your future one.

But, it is better to list it than not. Just don't add language that makes it problematic.